# Laravel-websocket: Apache + Vue + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Tengo una aplicación desacoplada. El frontend por un lado y el socket por el otro. El siguiente problema es que mi socket funciona solo en local y no sé cómo hacerlo funcionar en un hosting compartido. Instalé el paquete laravel-websocket y mi backend está hecho en laravel y mi frontend en vuejs.

Esta es mi configuración en el **config/broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher'                  => [
        'driver'                 => 'pusher',
        'key'                    => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret'                 => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id'                 => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options'                => [
            'cluster'               => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'useTLS'                => true,
            'encrypted'             => true,
            'host'                  => 'backtotal.test',
            'port'                  => 6001,
            'scheme'                => 'https',
            'curl_options'          => [
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
            ]
        ],
    ],
```

Esta es mi configuración en el **config/websocket.php**

```
'ssl' => [
    'local_cert' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT', null),

    'local_pk' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK', null),

    'passphrase' => env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_PASSPHRASE', null),
    
    'verify_peer' => false,

    'allow_self_signed' => true,
],
```

Variables en el archivo **.env** para los certificados:

```
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_CERT=/etc/ssl/certs/backtotal.crt
LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_SSL_LOCAL_PK=/etc/ssl/private/backtotal.key
```

Este es mi mi **main.js** en mi aplicación vuejs:

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '***************',
    cluster: 'tls',
    forceTLS: true,
    wsHost: 'backtotal.test',
    wssPort: 6001,
    wsPort: 6001,
    scheme: 'https',
    authEndpoint: `${config.url}/broadcasting/auth`,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    encrypted: false,
    auth: {
      headers: { 
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
      }
    }
});
```

He tratado de seguir este ejemplo que me encontré [Laravel + Nuxt + Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64477776/laravel-nuxt-nginx-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established/64512025#64512025)

Pero siempre me muestra este error cuando lo monto en producción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me pudiera ayudar o guiar, le agradecería mucho su ayuda.

### ACTUALIZACIÓN

He leído que necesito hacer un ProxyReverse para que mi socket tenga salida por un puerto con ssl. Estos han sido los intentos de crear un ProxyReverse desde Apache y continuo sin poder acoplar mi socket con mi frontend con ssl:

**INTENTO 1:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:6001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:6001

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/websocket.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/websocket.key
</VirtualHost>
```

**INTENTO 2:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    Include /etc/apache2/default-ssl.conf

    ServerName websocket.test
    ServerAlias *.websocket.test
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/backtotal.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/backtotal.key
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:6001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:6001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:6001/
</VirtualHost>
```

**INTENTO 3:**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/tastytotal/public

    <Directory /var/www/html/tastytotal/public>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:6001 retry=3 keepalive=On
    ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://127.0.0.1:6001 retry=3 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Habría que ver si ese hosting compartido permite conexiones por el puerto 6001. En general un webserver escucha en el 80 y en el 443,  y las peticiones que topen con el grupo de seguridad o el firewall nunca llegarán a Apache o Nginx.

Comment: Me parece raro en sí, por que si le hago en el terminal del host `netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN ` me muestra `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6001          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      34527/php` es decir, el puerto está abierto y escuchando.

Comment: Ya, pero y si haces un `nmap -p 6001 <host>` ?

Comment: Si hago desde mi máquina persona al hosting ese comando me devuelve esta respuesta `PORT     STATE    SERVICE
6001/tcp filtered X11:1
`

Comment: De la documentación de nmap: **Filtered** means that a firewall, filter, or other network obstacle is blocking the port so that Nmap cannot tell whether it is open or closed

Comment: Muchas gracias @ffflabs. Le echaré un ojo y cualquier cosa comento. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace poco tuve un problema similar para configurar un WebSocket, lo logré con Apache configurando [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) y [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html). Ten presente que debes realizar la conexión sobre *SSL* y tanto el Fronted como el Backend deben estar en el mismo hosting

Y lo que hice fue agregar a la configuración de mi virtualhost

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        <IfModule mod_proxy_wstunnel.c>
        ProxyPass /wss ws://127.0.0.1:8081 retry=0 keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse /wss ws://127.0.0.1:8081 retry=0
        </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

En el mismo Virtualhost garantizo que se realice una redirección de este dominio a *SSL* con esta configuración

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} = NOMBRE_DOMINIO.COM
       RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```